# QGIS Atlas export produces map in smaller scale then in composer

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-openlayers-plugin, atlas

I've loaded in QGIS 2.1, OSM map with OpenLayers plugin and I've created two rectangles representing coverage layer for Atlas. Then I've set Atlas in composer, first picture below. This preview should correspond to final page of the exported map. However, when I export Atlas in any format the scale of the picture is much smaller, see the second picture.

Did I miss anything or is this normal behaviour?

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: Item properties -> Main properties -> Scale -> *enter desired scale*
2. Go to: Item properties -> Controlled by atlas -> *select option* "Fixed scale", by default it's set to Margin arount feature 10%